# side-by-side translation

Tags: book-design

I have an english text translated into french and I want to print them side by side one page after the other. So that each french page is the translation of the english page.

```
--- page 1 ---
this is an english text
which spans over several pages
--- page 2 ---
ceci est un texte anglais
qui s'étale sur plusieurs pages
--- page 3 ---
this is the end of the english text
--- page 4 ---
ceci est la fin du texte en anglais
```

How could I achieve this with LaTeX ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple MWE using `reledpar` and `reledmac` to get you started ;)
Have a look at the [`reledpar`](https://ctan.org/pkg/reledpar?lang=en) documentation to do what you want.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}


\begin{document}
\huge % just for screenshot purposes

\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
\selectlanguage{english}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
--- page 1 ---
this is an english text
which spans over several pages
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\selectlanguage{french}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
--- page 2 ---
ceci est un texte anglais
qui s'étale sur plusieurs pages
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does "MWE" mean? Thanks for pointing me to this package, I'll investigate :)

Comment: It's very handy! I have to tweak some things like the page numbering, which isn't how I'd like it, but it's a very good starting point.

Comment: the page numbering can appear to be offset (2 and 3  instead of 1 and 2) because the package is placing the content into two actually facing pages. I wouldn't bother with that

Comment: @HugoTrentesaux MWE stands for [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), that is basically a passe partout to get help on this site. It helps both the parties involved: the community (because it has some code to work on) and the user, because he/she can focus on reproducing the issue. and, most of the time, issues get resolved while creating the MWE itself ;)